Medusajs Installation fails with error npx medusa db:migrate
I am trying to install medusajs ecommerce on my localhost.
I run according to the docs:
npx create-medusa-app@latest

and I answer the following on initial questions:
What's the name of your project? market2
Would you like to create the Next.js storefront? No
Enter your Postgres username? postgres
Enter your Postgres password? xxxxxx
Enter your Postgres user's database name? postgres

Then the proccess begins and succeed on the following steps:
 Starting project setup, this may take a few minutes.
✔ Created project directory
✔ Database medusa-market2 created
✔ Installed Dependencies
✔ Project Built

After this I get the error:
An error occurred while preparing project: Error: Command failed: npx medusa db:migrate

By looking at postress logs I see:
FATAL:  database "$DB_NAME" does not exist

UPDATE:
By Using --verbose
npx create-medusa-app@latest --verbose

I get these extra info:
redisUrl not found. A fake redis instance will be used.
{"level":"error","message":"Cannot sync links. database \"$DB_NAME\" does not exist","timestamp":"2024-11-02 20:33:04"}
{"level":"info","message":"Run command \"db:create\" to create the database","timestamp":"2024-11-02 20:33:04"}

ALSO:
On postgre logs I see the following:
2024-11-02 20:33:04.510 EET [151964] FATAL:  database "$DB_NAME" does not exist
2024-11-02 20:33:04.547 EET [151819] ERROR:  relation "mikro_orm_migrations" does not exist at character 15
2024-11-02 20:33:04.547 EET [151819] STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM "mikro_orm_migrations"
2024-11-02 20:33:04.554 EET [151819] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Η σύνδεση έκλεισε από το ταίρι

I don't how to proceed.
Any help is appreciated.
